# Using XMLHttpRequest I send a file to an MVC 3 controller method. How can I get the contents of the file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I am doing this:

```
 xhr.open('post', '/Fish/Create', true);
 xhr.send(file);
```

This produces a HTTP post that hits my controller method, and the contents of the file are being posted to it (as I can see in fiddler).

How can I get the contents out of the Request object?

For bonus points, I wonder if you can use a header or get a HttpPostedFileBase object. I can do something like `xhr.setRequestHeader("X-File-Name", "file");` and then in the controller method accept `object file` but I can't figure out what type the file is, or if it even created it correctly from stream.

I can't use FormData because it's not supported in IE9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
public JsonResult UploadPure()
   {
     string fileName = Request.Headers["X-File-Name"];
     string fileType = Request.Headers["X-File-Type"];
     int fileSize = int.Parse(Request.Headers["X-File-Size"]);
     System.IO.Stream fileContent = Request.InputStream;
     System.IO.FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/") + fileName);
     fileContent.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
     fileContent.CopyTo(fileStream);
     fileStream.Dispose();

     return Json("Uploaded files");
 }
```

it's work for me , for more info 
http://ajeeshms.in/Blog/Article/1/upload-files-using-ajax-in-asp-mvc
i hope it's help

Answer (score 3):

put a parameter of type `HttpPostedFileBase` in your controller action like this :

```
 public ActionResult PostFile(HttpPostedFileBase httpPostedFile)
 {
     var stream  = httpPostedFile.InputStream;
 }
```

Comment: Tried this, but it comes through as null, possibly because it can't map it to the variable name since it doesn't have one. Maybe some headers would do it?

Comment: i don't think name of variable is important here.

Comment: check Request.Files to see if it contains your posted file.

Comment: both Files and Form are empty. I've converted the InputStream into a string using some code I found on the net, which seems to have worked, but it's not the ideal solution.

Comment: @SLC why you don't use $.ajax or plugins like uploadify to send file to server?

Comment: Because I don't want to use flash, and $.ajax won't post files. And IE9 doesn't support reading local files either, much to my chagrin.